# Can Luis be used in Bots designed on platform other than MSFT Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

Can Luis be used in Bots designed on a platform other than MSFT Bot Framework like chatfeul.

Comment: LUIS doesn't support Chatfuel directly. But there's a workaround - Once you train a LUIS model successfully, you will be getting an endpoint. You can send params to this endpoint and get responses from it in JSON format. You can use this within your code. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Moreover, almost every action in LUIS portal can be done with this API instead of using the portal: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f

Answer (score 3):

After training a LUIS model, you get an endpoint which is a REST service that can be called. You can then pass parameters to this, modify it according to need and get a JSON response.

You can read more about connecting an API to chatfuel [here](https://community.chatfuel.com/t/easily-connecting-api-ai-to-chatfuel/3084)